Digital Microphone Readings to dB SPL
I've seen previous answers on how to calculate the dB SPL based on my I2S readings but I can't come up with a formula to calculate it.
I use the MSM261S4030H0 I2S microphone with sensitivity of -26 dB FS and the bit resolution I am using with the I2S protocol is 16-bit. Based on previous answers when an input of 1 kHz and 1 Pa is applied to the microphone diaphragm the digital positive peak value of the output with 16-bit resolution will be 32767 * 0.0501 = 1641.
So then can I use a simple method for calculating the dB SPL in my code like  if the reading of positive value is 1000 then the dB SPL will be dBSPL = 94*1000 / 1641 = 57.28?


So then can I use a simple method for calculating the dB SPL in my code like if the reading of positive value is 1000 then the dB SPL will be dBSPL = 94*1000 / 1641 = 57.28?

No, you have to work in decibels.
If
amplitude = 1641 * 10^((dB - 94) / 20)

then
dB = 20 * log(amplitude / 1641) + 94

(where log is to the base 10).
So for a peak reading of 1000 that's 20 log(1000 / 1641) + 94 = 89.7 dB SPL.
Incidentally, that means that normal conversational volume (40-60 dB SPL at 1 meter distance) is only a digital reading of ±3 units at the low end, to ±30 units at the high end. Depending on your usecase, that might be a bit deaf.

Thanks for the answer. So I am planning to perform FFT to the input signal and get each frequency amplitude from there, will this formula "20 log(frequency amplitude / 1641) + 94" work to calculate the dBSPL ? Sorry but I dont have the knowledge wet to able to fully understand

No because you are just linearly scaling decibels and decibels are not linear units but a logarithmic ratio of two values. You can't use a simple method.
If 1642 is -26dBFS, 32767 is 0dBFS.
If your mic outputs -26dB FS with 94dB SPL reference tone, then converting calculated dBFS to dB SPL is simple - just add the offset in dB.

Thanks for the answer. Do you mean the offset of FullScale? For example if my reading is 900 the dBFS will be -31.22dBFS +94  and the dBSPL will be -31.22 +94 ?

@PhazeMusic No, because you already said 1621 equals -26 dB FS which equals 1 Pa which equals 94 dB SPL.
